# Classes registration in Wordpress useing woocommers

Tags: plugins

About:
I have some clients that has classes of different kind, we use wordpress as a platform, with woocommerce, elementor and crocoblock, under is an example of what I’m looking for and have not found.
Using: (This is what’s installed, and I want to use to design and make this work)
•   WordPress
•   Elementor
•   JetEngine (crocoblock plugins)
•   WooCommerce
•   Some more plugins to make this work

User case:
Customer sells live courses with one or more instructors, either in a gym or pool, courses are usually once a week lasting from 30 min. to 2 hours over an 8 – 15-week period, during holidays they can have 5 days in a row, lasting whole day from 9am – 15pm, or 30-45 min. starting the same time every day. During the 8–15-week period there could be some days that are holidays, so granular control of course days must be possible.

Example:
New swimming class starts Monday sept. 9 at 6 pm and last for 30 minutes until 6:30 pm, it will have 6 sessions, all at the same time, so last session will be Monday oct. 11 at 6pm until 6:30pm, price for all sessions will be $150.
What the client wants to add is just the first session date and start-/end time or session length as in the example 30 min, then number of sessions and price, the rest of the dates, should be automatically added.

Repeat function:
Every weekday, every other week, once a month, the next number of days.

I have been looking around, testing a lot of plugins but haven’t found any, so I hope someone has any idea as I don’t want to use the time on development of a new plugin for this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: That is what I have done, I'm in need of a pointer towards a plugin that can help solve the problem, and I have no idea of how to shorten it